# How to reverse file read?

Tags: java, file-io, reverse

How would I reverse the output of the .txt file?
An example:

The input file contents:

This is the beginning of the file.

Second line.

This is the third line.

Fourth Line.

The end of the file.

Should be read in and the following file printed:

The end of the file.

Fourth Line.

This is the third line.

Second line.

This is the beginning of the file.

This is the code I have currently:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileCopier {

     public static void copyCharacters() throws IOException {
            FileReader inputStream = null;
            FileWriter outputStream = null;

            try {
                inputStream = new FileReader("Motown.txt");
                outputStream = new FileWriter("Motown_output.txt");

                int c;
                while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
         }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            copyCharacters();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What input are you feeding it (i.e. what's in your file), and what output are you getting?  A sample will do.  Also, what is the exact shape of the output you're hoping for?

Comment: Motown.txt: The city of Detroit
Its in eastern Michigan
Known as the motor city
used to be one of the largest car producers
now what is it? - this is the .txt file I'm feeding into it

Comment: Be sure to add this in your question.  Comments are just for comments.  The more detail you add in your question, the more likely people are able to help you at a glance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should be able to

1. read your input line by line
2. read each line into a collection
3. reverse the collection

Here, I'm using a Deque and getting its descendingIterator:

```
 public static void copyCharacters() throws IOException {
            FileWriter outputStream = null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

            Deque<String> fileContents = new ArrayDeque<>();

            try {
                outputStream = new FileWriter("motown_output.txt");
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("motown.txt"));

                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    fileContents.add(line);
                }

                for (Iterator<String> iterator = fileContents.descendingIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                    outputStream.write(iterator.next());
                    outputStream.write("\n");
                }

            } finally {
                if (bufferedReader != null) {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
         }
```